# Shebang does not set SHELL in cron

Tags: bash, shell, cron, shebang

I have a script containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
printenv
```

When I run it from the command line:

```
env testscript.sh
bash testscript.sh
sh testscript.sh
```

every time, it outputs `SHELL=/bin/bash`. However, when it is run from the cron, it always outputs `SHELL=/bin/sh`. Why is this? How can I make cron apply the shebang?

I already checked the cron PATH; it does include /bin.

Comment: Shell scripts in general do not change environment variables so the value of SHELL will not change. First check to see if /bin/sh is a link to bash - it is on many systems. If /bin/sh is something else link dash, try using the bash specific commands you need and see if they fail. Finally, you can use something like '[ -z $BASH ] && { exec bash "$0" "$@" || exit; }' as the first line in your script to make sure you're running it under bash.

Comment: What distro is this?

Comment: Read `man 5 crontab`. cron sets environment variables SHELL, LOGNAME, HOME and PATH.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shebang is working and cron has nothing to do with that. When a file is executed, if that file's content begins with `#!`, the kernel executes the file specified on the `#!` line and passes it the original file as an argument.

Your problem is that you seem to believe that `SHELL` in a shell script reflects the shell that is executing the script. This is not the case. In fact, in most contexts, `SHELL` means the user's prefered **interactive** shell, it is meant for applications such as terminal emulator to decide which shell to execute. In cron, `SHELL` is the variable that tells cron what program to use to run the crontab entries (the part of the lines after the time indications).

Shells do not set the `SHELL` variable unless it is not set when they start.

The fact that `SHELL` is `/bin/sh` is very probably irrelevant. Your script has a `#!/bin/bash` line, so it's executed by bash. If you want to convince yourself, add `ps $$` in the script to make `ps` show information about the shell executing the script.

Answer (score 2):

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) says:

> SHELL - The full pathname to the shell is kept in this environment variable. If it is not set when the shell starts, Bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user’s login shell.

[`man 5 crontab`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5) says:

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by  the  cron(8) daemon. SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the /etc/passwd  line  of   the   crontab's   owner.   PATH   is   set   to "/usr/bin:/bin".   HOME,  SHELL, and PATH may be overridden by settings in the crontab

So the `SHELL` variable is set when the Bash start.

Try `SHELL=/bin/awesome/shell bash testcript.sh`. You should see `SHELL=/bin/awesome/shell`

Shebang works. You have a documented behaviour:)

Answer (score 0):

> However, when it is run from the cron, it always outputs SHELL=/bin/sh. Why is this?

This is because cron set `SHELL` to `/bin/sh` as this is the default program cron uses to run crontab entries. From `man 5 crontab`:

> Several  environment  variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh...

And as already indicated by the answer of Evgeny Vereshchagin, that variable won't be modified by Bash later if it is already set.

> How can I make cron apply the shebang?

Cron is already applying it **for your own script**, as you can see from the following example.

Let's say you have the following `display_process_tree.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$$
depth=0
while
    [ "$pid" -gt 0 ] &&
    read -r ppid name < <(ps -o ppid= -o comm= -p "$pid")
do
    eval $(echo printf '" %0.s"' {0..$depth})
    if [[ -r /proc/$pid/exe ]]; then    
    echo -n "$name - "
    readlink -f /proc/$pid/exe
    else
    echo $name
    fi
    pid=$ppid
    depth=$((depth+1))
done
```

And a crontab like this:

```
* * * * * /path/to/display_process_tree.sh > /tmp/display_process_tree.log
```

Now, if you wait for the output to arrive to `/tmp/display_process_tree.log`, you will find a process tree like the following:

```
 display_process - /bin/bash
  sh - /bin/dash
   cron
    cron
     systemd
```

That shows that cron actually used `/bin/sh` (linked to `/bin/dash` in my system) to open a new `/bin/bash` process for your script.

Answer (score -1):

Change the shebang to

```
#!/bin/env bash
```

Or execute `crontab -e` to have the script run with your own environment variables, as cron's own are different.

---

As a side note, according to [this post on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work?lq=1), you need to give your `cron` a PATH at the top of the script:

```
PATH=/opt/someApp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# rest of script follows
```

However, given that you said PATH seems to have the proper search directories,you can rule that out.

Comment: Benubird is not experiencing behaviour that can be caused by a wrong PATH or a wrong path to the shell.

Comment: Yah, I saw that bit after I added the part about the PATH; decided to leave it there, nonetheless.  This question has multiple versions floating around on here.

Comment: @Wieland, if his PATH is fine, then `env bash` should work, no? Ultimately, the question is "How can I make cron apply the shebang"!

Comment: Yes, but the path to his bash is already correct, otherwise there would be no output at all.

Comment: Your downvotes sting like soap in my eyes